# Date Formatting using SimpleDateFormat

Tags: java, validation, date

Here the user need to enter the Name, Date of Birth and Date of joining. The program need to check whether the entered date is valid with any of the given 3 formats `dd/MM/yyyy` , `dd-MMM-yyyy` and `dd MMMM yyyy`. If invalid, user need to re-enter. Finally i want to print back an auto-increment ID,Name,Date of Birth and Date of Joining back. Can you help me with the program. I cannot find any solution for exception handling.

```
public class EmployeeInfo {
int id;
static String name, DoBS, DoJS;
Date DoB, DoJ;

public void checkDate(String dt) throws ParseException {

    SimpleDateFormat sdf1 = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
    SimpleDateFormat sdf2 = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy");
    SimpleDateFormat sdf3 = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMMM yyyy");

    Date date = null;
    if (date == sdf1.parse(dt))

        try {
            date = sdf1.parse(dt);
        }


        catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

            DoB=date;

        }
    else if (date == sdf2.parse(dt))
        try {
            System.out.println("hsd");
            date = sdf2.parse(dt);
        } 
    catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    else if(date==sdf3.parse(dt))

{
        try{
            date=sdf3.parse(dt);
    }
        catch(ParseException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
}

{



void print() {
    System.out.println("User ID: " + id);
    System.out.println("Name: " + name);
    System.out.println("Date Of Birth: " + DoB);
    System.out.println("Date of Joining: " + DoJ);
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter the name: ");
    name = scanner.nextLine();

    System.out.println("Enter the Date Of Birth: ");
    DoBS = scanner.nextLine();

    System.out.println("Enter the Date of Joining: ");
    DoJS = scanner.nextLine();

    EmployeeInfo e = new EmployeeInfo();
    e.checkDate(DoBS);
    e.print();
}
}
```

Comment: Write a  `Date tryParse(String date, DateFormat format)` method that swallows the exception.

Comment: You are using troublesome old date-time classes that are now legacy, supplanted by the java.time classes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As for the actual checking of dates, if you only want to support those three date formats you could simply use three nested try catch statements. Something like this:

```
try {
    date = sdf1.parse(dt);
} catch (ParseException e) {
    try {
        date = sdf2.parse(dt);
    } catch (ParseException e1) {
        try {
            date = sdf3.parse(dt);
        } catch (ParseException e2) {
            // TODO: Whatever to do when it doesn't find a date
        }
    }
}
```

If you want a more dynamic approach you could put the SimpleDateFormat objects in an array and use a loop with a try-catch inside.

EDIT:
Alright, what you want to do is make the `checkDate` method return a Date object. If it can't parse a date in your three formats, either return null or throw an exception. When entering the dates, you want to have a while loop checking whether or not the date is valid, using the `checkDate` method, and make the user reenter if it's invalid.

A few notes about your code:
In Java, fields of classes are usually private, with getter and setter methods to control them - this is called encapsulation.
Static fields are meant for variables that are the same across all of your instances. Name and dates specific to one EmployeeInfo object should not be static. You should create an EmployeeInfo object and then set the respective values of the object.
It is also common practice to have all your methods be either private or public (or protected in the case of inheritance) depending on their intended usage.

I suggest you read up a little on the basics of OOP in Java.

Comment: i got this. thanks. But i have two input date strings. Date of Birth and Date of Joining. while trying to print, both of then return same. can you help me out with that?..

Answer (score 0):

You asked several things in your question but regarding the date-paersing issue, you could implement it like following :

```
private static final List<DateFormat> ORDERED_FORMATS = Arrays.asList(new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy"),new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy"),new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM yyyy"));

public static Date parseDate(String date) {
    for(DateFormat format : ORDERED_FORMATS){
        Date result = tryParse(date, format);
        if(result != null){
            return result;
        }
    }
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Could not parse "+date);
}

private static Date tryParse(String date, DateFormat format){
    try{
        return format.parse(date);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        System.out.println("Too bad : "+e.getMessage());
    }
    return null;
}
```